# Kendo MVVM observable array item not updated when value is emptied

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I have a `hidden` input used to create a best looking dropdownlist using Select2 plugin. This `hidden` field is bound to my observables and it is updating the value in the observable when the value changes. But when I change the dropdownlist to an empty value, the `hidden` input is updated (value is empty) however the observable keeps the previous value.

```
<input type="hidden" id="leader" style="width: 300px" data-bind="value: filter.leader" />
```

So, if I select `Item 1` in the dropdownlist, the `hidden` field and the observable `filter.leader` are updated. If I deselect the `Item 1`, only the `hidden` field is updated.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. It's related to the Select2 plugin not triggering a change event when I call `$('#control').select2('val','')`. So, basically what I had to do was to call `trigger('change')` after the previous command.

Like this:

```
$('#control').select2('val','').trigger('change')
```